# How can I take a photo using Camera from EasyAR library?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camera2, easyar

I have AR Android App. I'm using EasyAR library for some AR functionality and now I wanna add "taking photo" functionality. When user is using the AR camera, he can press a button to take a photo and save it to gallery. How can I do that?

I tried to find this functionality in official EasyAR documentation and there's nothing about taking photos. Maybe I missed something, but I didn't find anything. And one more solution, that I tried is taking screenshot of camera preview. I know, that it's very bad solution, but I don't know what can I do in this case. So, this solution didn't work because when I take a screenshot the camera preview area is all black. I assume this is a deliberate limitation of Android due to security reasons.

Please help if you know way how to do this functionality. It doesn’t matter how - by means of EasyAR or in some other way. I will be glad to any answers, thank you in advance for your help